# How to save and retrieve ListItems in Android

Tags: android

How to save state of list items so that i can retrieve it back on restart of phone. Currently in below code you can see i have a listview which has a list items. Now I want to save the state of "items" during onDestroy and onPause and retrieve back during onCreate (Reason for doing this is to retrieve state of data when phone is restarted). Can someone help with code.

```
public class LogListView extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static String newString;
    private static EntryAdapter adapter;
    int clickCounter = 0;
    static ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    static SharedPreferences preferences = null;
    private static Context context = null;
    static StringTokenizer tokens;
    private static String first;
    private static String second;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = this;
        adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, items);
        // items.add(new SectionItem("Log Report"));
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        if (adapter.getCount() != 0) {
            // Do nothing Adapter has value
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(LogListView.this, "No Items Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Retrive Preference here when Adapter is null

        }

    }

    // Method which will handle dynamic insertion
    public static void addItems() {

        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("LOG",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        newString = preferences.getString("log", "");

        tokens = new StringTokenizer(newString, ",");
        first = tokens.nextToken();
        second = tokens.nextToken();

        items.add(new EntryItem(first, second));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    // Method which will handle dynamic insertion ends

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        //Save preference here


    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        if (!items.get(position).isSection()) {

            items.get(position);
            // Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + item.title ,
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }

        if (position == 9) {

        }

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Torben : Nop, this is completely different issue

Comment: It is the same issue. The "state" you are saving is the contents of the list. Start by reading the links and implementing the basic state saving boilerplate. Then if you get stuck with saving the actual items, come back and ask a more detailed question.

Comment: The purpose of StackOverflow is not to get ready made solutions. We give pointers to information so that you can study and learn for yourself. I gave you one, so please have some courtesy and go study it before dismissing it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If I have to save a List to SharedPreferences I always chose to do the following, you're going to need the Gson library for this, though.

First convert the list to a JSON String:

```
Type listOfObjects = new TypeToken<List<YourObject>>(){}.getType();
String json = gson.toJson(list, listOfObjects);
```

Then save the String to the preferences. To convert the json back to the list do the following:

```
Type listOfObjects = new TypeToken<List<YourObject>>(){}.getType();
List<YourObject> list = gson.fromJson(json, listOfObjects);
```